# Replace with regular expression repetition

Tags: python, regex

I would like use regular expression to replace a pattern by an other :

```
re.compile(r"<class '(.*)'>").sub("\\1", "<class 'int'>")
>>> 'int'
```

But how can i manage repetition cases ? Like:

```
re.compile(r"<class '(.*)'>").sub("\\1", "<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>")
>>> 'int\'>, <class \'str'  # i would like 'int, str'
```

Comment: If you want to extract, use `re.findall`, and a lazy dot, `.*?`

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew, can you provide an example ? I am not familiar with python `re`module.

Comment: `re.compile(r"<class '(.*?)'>").sub("\\1", "<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>")`  this will work fine as Wiktor has mentioned.

Comment: This is working like a charm, thanks !

Comment: If you want to get a list, `['int', 'str']`, use `re.findall(r"<class '(.*?)'>", text)`